# Erro ao iniciar um novo app no Ionic

Tags: android, ionic, git, mobile

Estou iniciando um projeto no *Ionic*, estou apenas seguindo os passos iniciais, ao passar o comando:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

Está gerando o seguinte erro

```
? Connect this app to the Ionic Dashboard? No
> git add -A
> git commit -m "Initial commit" --no-gpg-sign
[ERROR] An error occurred while running git commit -m "Initial commit" --no-gpg-sign (exit code 128):
```

Obs: Já instalei o Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já configurou o *Git* ?

Para fazer um *Commit*, o *Git* precisa saber seu nome e seu endereço de e-mail.

O objetivo da ferramenta, não é apenas rastrear as mudanças de código, mas quem fez as mudanças!

Para configurar, execute os comandos abaixo, informando seu *Nome* e *Email*.

```
git config --global user.name "SEU NOME" // Para configurar o nome
git config --global user.email "seuemail@servico.com" // Para configurar o email
```

> Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45665214/8353154)